# How to detect collisions between objects in LibGDX

Tags: java, arraylist, libgdx, collision-detection, game-development

This is my first post on stack overflow so I apologize in advance if I'm breaking any rules about posting, etc.  I have been working on a an asteroids-*esque* shooting game and I can't figure out how to get the collision detection working between the rocks and the laser.
The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Apress/java-game-dev-LibGDX/tree/master/Ch04%20Space%20Rocks). I had to make some changes to the update method of LevelScreen because the original code is dependent on using the BlueJ IDE. I found a fix in this [post](https://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=27923&start=10) and got the collision working between the spaceship and the rocks.

The LevelScreen class

```
    package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LevelScreen extends BaseScreen {

    private Spaceship spaceship;
    private boolean gameOver;
    private boolean rocksNeedRemoved;
    private Rock toRemove;

    private ArrayList<Rock> rocks;
    private ArrayList<Laser> lasers;

    public void initialize() {

        gameOver = false;
        toRemove = null;
        rocksNeedRemoved = false;

        BaseActor space = new BaseActor(0, 0, mainStage);
        space.loadTexture("space.png");
        space.setSize(800, 600);
        BaseActor.setWorldBounds(space);

        spaceship = new Spaceship(400, 300, mainStage);

        rocks = new ArrayList<Rock>();
        lasers = new ArrayList<Laser>();

        rocks.add(new Rock(600, 500, mainStage));
        rocks.add(new Rock(600, 300, mainStage));
        rocks.add(new Rock(600, 100, mainStage));
        rocks.add(new Rock(400, 100, mainStage));
        rocks.add(new Rock(200, 100, mainStage));
        rocks.add(new Rock(200, 300, mainStage));
        rocks.add(new Rock(200, 500, mainStage));
        rocks.add(new Rock(400, 500, mainStage));

        lasers.add(new Laser(400, 500, mainStage));


    }

    public void update(float dt) {


        //Code from book(Throws class not found error)
        /*
        for (BaseActor rockActor : BaseActor.getList(mainStage, 
            "Rock")) {

            if (rockActor.overlaps(spaceship)) {

                if (spaceship.shieldPower <= 0) {

                    Explosion boom = new Explosion(0, 0, 
                        mainStage);
                    boom.centerAtActor(spaceship);
                    spaceship.remove();
                    spaceship.setPosition(-1000, -1000);

                    BaseActor messageLose = new BaseActor(0, 0, 
                        uiStage);
                    messageLose.loadTexture("message- 
                        lose.png");
                    messageLose.centerAtPosition(400, 300);
                    messageLose.setOpacity(0);
                    messageLose.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(1));
                    gameOver = true;
                }
                else {

                    spaceship.shieldPower -= 34;
                    Explosion boom = new Explosion(0, 0, 
                        mainStage);
                    boom.centerAtActor(rockActor);
                    rockActor.remove();
                }
            }

            for (BaseActor laserActor : 
                BaseActor.getList(mainStage, "Laser")) {

                if (laserActor.overlaps(rockActor)) {

                }
                Explosion boom = new Explosion(0, 0, 
                    mainStage);
                boom.centerAtActor(rockActor);
                laserActor.remove();
                rockActor.remove();
            }
        }

        if (!gameOver && BaseActor.count(mainStage, "Rock") == 
            0) {

            BaseActor messageWin = new BaseActor(0, 0, 
                uiStage);
            messageWin.loadTexture("message-win.png");
            messageWin.centerAtPosition(400, 300);
            messageWin.setOpacity(0);
            messageWin.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(1));
            gameOver = true;
        }

    }

         */





        // loop I used to get collision working between rocks 
            and spaceship

        for (Rock each : rocks)
            if (spaceship.overlaps(each) && !each.crashed && 
                spaceship.shieldPower <= 0) {
                Explosion boom = new Explosion(0, 0, 
                    mainStage);
                Explosion boom2 = new Explosion(0, 0, 
                    mainStage);
                boom.centerAtActor(spaceship);
                boom2.centerAtActor(each);

                spaceship.remove();
                spaceship.setPosition(-1000, -1000);
                each.crashed = true;
                each.clearActions();
                each.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1));

    each.addAction(Actions.after(Actions.removeActor()));
                rocksNeedRemoved = true;
                toRemove = each;

            } else if (spaceship.overlaps(each) && 
                  !each.crashed) {
                Explosion boom = new Explosion(0, 0, 
                    mainStage);
                boom.centerAtActor(each);
                spaceship.shieldPower -= 34;
                each.crashed = true;
                each.clearActions();
                each.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1));

    each.addAction(Actions.after(Actions.removeActor()));
                rocksNeedRemoved = true;
                toRemove = each;
            }

        //check for collision between rocks and lasers (Not 
          working correctly)

        for (int i = rocks.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Rock rock = rocks.get(i);
            for (int j = lasers.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                Laser laser = lasers.get(j);

    if(rock.getBounds().overlaps(laser.getBounds())) {
                    Explosion boom = new Explosion(0, 0, 
                        mainStage);
                    boom.centerAtActor(rock);
                    rock.crashed = true;
                    rock.clearActions();
                    rock.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1));

    rock.addAction(Actions.after(Actions.removeActor()));
                    rocksNeedRemoved = true;
                    toRemove = rock;
                }
            }
        }

    }







    //override default InputProcessor method
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

        if (keycode == Keys.X)
            spaceship.warp();

        if (keycode == Keys.SPACE)
            spaceship.shoot();

        return false;
    }
}
```

The Spaceship class.

```
    package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;

public class Spaceship extends BaseActor {

    private Thrusters thrusters;
    private Shield shield;
    public int shieldPower;

    public Spaceship(float x, float y, Stage s) {

        super(x, y, s);

        loadTexture("spaceship.png");
        setBoundaryPolygon(8);

        setAcceleration(100);
        setMaxSpeed(100);
        setDeceleration(10);

        thrusters = new Thrusters(0, 0, s);
        addActor(thrusters);
        thrusters.setPosition(-thrusters.getWidth(), 
            getHeight() / 2 - thrusters.getHeight() / 2);

        shield = new Shield(0, 0, s);
        addActor(shield);
        shield.centerAtPosition(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 
            2);
        shieldPower = 100;

    }

    public void act(float dt) {

        super.act(dt);

        float degreesPerSecond = 160; //rotation speed
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT))
            rotateBy(degreesPerSecond * dt);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
            rotateBy(-degreesPerSecond * dt);

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
            accelerateAtAngle(getRotation());
            thrusters.setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            thrusters.setVisible(false);
        }

        shield.setOpacity(shieldPower / 100f);
        if (shieldPower <= 0)
            shield.setVisible(false);

        applyPhysics(dt);

        wrapAroundWorld();
    }

    public void warp() {

        if(getStage() == null)
            return;

        Warp warp1 = new Warp(0, 0, this.getStage());
        warp1.centerAtActor(this);
        setPosition(MathUtils.random(800), 
            MathUtils.random(600));
        Warp warp2 = new Warp(0, 0, this.getStage());
        warp2.centerAtActor(this);
    }

    public void shoot() {

        if (getStage() == null)
            return;

        Laser laser = new Laser(0, 0, this.getStage());
        laser.centerAtActor(this);
        laser.setRotation(this.getRotation());
        laser.setMotionAngle(this.getRotation());


    }
}
```

The Laser class.

```
    package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Action;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;

public class Laser extends BaseActor {

    Rectangle bounds;

    public Laser(float x, float y, Stage s) {

        super(x, y, s);
        bounds = new Rectangle((int)getX(), (int)getY(), 
             (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());






        loadTexture("laser.png");

        addAction(Actions.delay(1));
        addAction(Actions.after(Actions.fadeOut(0.5f)));
        addAction(Actions.after(Actions.removeActor()));

        setSpeed(400);
        setMaxSpeed(400);
        setDeceleration(0);
    }

    public void act(float dt) {

        super.act(dt);
        applyPhysics(dt);
        wrapAroundWorld();
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    private void setXY(float pX,float pY) {
        setPosition(pX, pY);
        bounds.setX((int)pX);
        bounds.setY((int)pY);
    }

}
```

The Rock class

```
    package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Action;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.mygdx.game.BaseActor;

public class Rock extends BaseActor {


    public boolean crashed;
    Rectangle bounds;

    public Rock(float x, float y, Stage s) {

        super(x, y, s);

        bounds = new Rectangle((int)getX(), (int)getY(), 
            (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());



        loadTexture("rock.png");

        float random = MathUtils.random(30);

        addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.rotateBy(30 + random, 
            1)));

        setSpeed(50 + random);
        setMaxSpeed(50 + random);
        setDeceleration(0);
        setMotionAngle(MathUtils.random(360));

        crashed = false;
    }

    public void act(float dt) {


        super.act(dt);
        applyPhysics(dt);
        wrapAroundWorld();
    }



    public boolean isCrashed() {
        return crashed;
    }

    public void crashed() {

        crashed = true;
        clearActions();
        addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1));
        addAction(Actions.after(Actions.removeActor()));

    }
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    private void setXY(float pX,float pY) {
        setPosition(pX, pY);
        bounds.setX((int)pX);
        bounds.setY((int)pY);
    }
}
```

Boundary and overlap methods from BaseActor class

```
public void setBoundaryPolygon(int numSides) {

        float w = getWidth();
        float h = getHeight();
        float[] vertices = new float[2 * numSides];

        for(int i = 0; i < numSides; i ++) {

            float angle = i * 6.28f / numSides;
            //x coordinate
            vertices[2 * i] = w / 2 * MathUtils.cos(angle) + w / 2;
            //y coordinate
            vertices[2 * i + 1] = h / 2 * MathUtils.sin(angle) + h / 2;

        }

        boundaryPolygon = new Polygon(vertices);
    }

    public Polygon getBoundaryPolygon() {

        boundaryPolygon.setPosition(getX(), getY());
        boundaryPolygon.setOrigin(getOriginX(), getOriginY());
        boundaryPolygon.setRotation(getRotation());
        boundaryPolygon.setScale(getScaleX(), getScaleY());
        return boundaryPolygon;
    }

    public boolean overlaps(BaseActor other) {

        Polygon poly1 = this.getBoundaryPolygon();
        Polygon poly2 = other.getBoundaryPolygon();

        //initial text to improve performance
        if(!poly1.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(poly2.getBoundingRectangle()))
            return false;

        return Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(poly1, poly2);
    }
```

So I guess the real question would be how would I go about checking for collisions between the rocks ArrayList and the lasers fired by the player? At this point I just want to finish the game even if it's not using best practices.  I tried using the method described [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87889/libgdx-how-to-check-collision-of-randomly-generated-actors) and received no errors but also no collision between lasers and rock. Even if I manually add a laser to the lasers ArrayList. This last [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124175/libgdx-collision-detection-between-all-bullets-and-all-enemies?rq=1) I found leads me to believe I need something like a getAllLasers() but I'm not 100% sure how to go about that. Would it be easier to just learn Box2D or Quadtree?

I realize this is a complex problem and want to thank you in advance for taking taking the time to read it. I'm happy to provide any more information you need.

Comment: This code will be hard to go through it all, Please read this '[create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)' then try to ask again with the problem you're having.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working correctly"? how is it working and how you expect it to work? also is there any reason why you casting `floats` to `ints` when updating `bounds` ? `rock.getBounds().overlaps(laser.getBounds())` should work just fine. If `Rock` or `Laser` are scaled or rotated you should update your bounds accordingly

Comment: What I am try to do exactly is remove a rock if it is hit by a laser.  I got rid of the casted ints and it works the same.  I'm wondering if the laser is not being added to the array list? Even if I stop the rotation and motion of the rocks, there is no collision between them and the laser.  I will take advice above and re ask in a more appropriate way with more relevant information. Thanks

Comment: Your code is too long to read. I'm guessing that your `Rectangle`s aren't where they suppose to be. Just override `drawDebug` method on both `Laser` and `Rock` and draw their `bounds` there, see an example https://ibb.co/jDTYtyv. Then launch the game and see if the `Rectangle`s are drawn in conjunction with the actor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  `bounds.set(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());` is what I was missing. After that I just had to add the laser to an arraylist  in the shoot method and everything worked properly.

Comment: No problem.  I just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `Rectangle` bounds for both of this entities, this is all you need. You can use `Rectangle.overlaps()`

```
for(Laser laser: lasers){
   for(Rock rock: rocks){
      if(laser.getBounds().overlaps(rock.getBounds())){
         //collided! 
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure you are getting a updated rectangle/bounds. Add this extra line in both `Rock` and `Laser` `getBounds()` method:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
   bounds.set(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
   return bounds;
}
```

if your actors scales or rotate you should update `bounds` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think problem may be with update your actors bounds, i can't find where you update it. I wrote similiar game and i change `Bound`s of actors on each update step and all works well in some lines...

```
public void update() {
...
        // changing bounds
        bounds = new Rectangle(position.x,position.y,
                actorWidth,
                actorHeight);
}
```

Or if you use other approach check that your bounds changing in time

Comment: Creating a rectangle each frame isn't a good idea, this will create 60 new objects in the heap per second . Instead use `bounds.set(...)`  or even better. Update it just before you need it in `getBounds()`

Comment: Yep, the main idea was to update the values in bounds the way you do this may be different